# Can an LED emit photons with energy (in $\rm eV$) larger than the voltage drop across it (in $\rm V$)?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, photon-emission, light-emitting-diodes

I recently had a discussion with someone who told me that they have a UVC (260 nm - 270 nm) LED with a forward voltage of 3.3 V. I told them that this must be impossible, because an electron dropping through a 3.3 V drop will produce in the best case scenario a 3.3 eV photon, which is 376 nm. So, at best, their 3.3 V LED is UVA - but more likely closer to 400 nm blue light due to inefficiencies. I argued that the forward voltage required to emit 260 nm (4.8 eV) light is higher than 4.8 V - and the datasheets that I do find do indeed state forward voltages of 5 V - 7 V for UVC LEDs.

They claim that LEDs do not work like this - that the relationship between the voltage drop in V and the photon energy in eV is not this simple, and that among the many complex processes that happen in the p-n junction it is easy for the energy to 'build up' to generate higher energy photons.

In my view, creating an emissive excited state with an energy higher than the voltage drop would amount to an up-conversion. I am familiar with photon up-conversion in nanoparticles - in an upconverting nanoparticle, the collision of long-lived diffusive excitons can take a lanthanide ion into a higher excited emissive state - which then emits a higher energy photon. In that particular case the process is a non-linear optical process with low efficiency, and the system works because of the very special spacing of the energy levels in the lanthanide ions and their symmetries.

I don't know enough about the solid-state physics of LEDs, but I am reasoning that creating a 5 eV exciton using a 3.3V drop would require a process in which the energy form two electrons dropping is up-converted. I think that it would take a very specially designed system and very high currents to achieve that - and the efficiency would be low. I don't think that standard LEDs can do this. But perhaps I am wrong and semi-conductor physics has a different set of rules and up-conversion is very common, or I am looking at this in completely the wrong way.

So, to keep the question simple: Can an LED emit photons with energy (in eV) larger than the voltage drop across it (in V)?

Comment: I would agree with you. Attached data sheet link. http://www.qphotonics.com/Deep-UV-light-emitting-diode-0.4mW-265nm-UVLED265TO46FW.html

Comment: LEDs can emit for forward bias below the bandgap https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-022-31478-y